# How can I write a dynamic amount of lines and assign them to array in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, user-input

Hi I am trying to write some lines to an array in C, and the amount of lines depends on the first input from the user.

My program ends unexpected after 2nd iteration even though I ask to loop 8 times.

```c
int main(){
    char line[32];
    fgets(line, 32, stdin); //Get the (int)amount of future input lines
    int n = atoi(line); 

    char *array[n]; // Create an array to hold the future lines
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        fgets(array[i], 32, stdin); //Get a line and assign to array
    }   
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }   
    return 0;
```

Comment: What is the greatest line length expected?  (Not asking about the amount of lines.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *array[n];
```

This line creates an array of n elements of type char *, thus an array of pointers. As they are not initialized, you are ending up with writing bytes into arbitrary addresses in the memory, leading to crash.

You need to either allocate 32 bytes of memory for each element of your array with malloc(), or declare an array of n char[32] elements (thus each element is a 32 chars array):

```
char array[n][32];
```